# Docking station for Macbook Pro that lets you use the book + external monitor

Tags: hardware, lightning

Does a docking station exist for MacBook Pros that let you dock it and keep the book open, so you can still use the keyboard, trackpad and monitor plus let you have an auxiliary monitor connected. I am debating ordering a Thinkpad with dock vs. a MacBook Pro but the user I am ordering it for loves her two monitors and was using a Win XP desktop. We are going to switch her to a mobile machine but the "docking" solution is very appealing and manually hooking up a second monitor all the time is not that appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't that many on the market (most users are happy to connect the mac cables manually).  However this solution looks pretty nice :

http://www.bookendzdocks.com/

Hope this helps.

PS Here is another solution,

http://www.hengedocks.com/

but doesn't allow the macbook to remain open, so you'd need an external monitor, keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Thanks Rob!  The bookends is a solution to my issue, I have passed this on to the user. It looks to be as about as an elegant solution as one can get since apple did not design it with docking in mind.